# How to easily get these values from a 2d matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix

I have this 2d numpy matrix

```
a = np.array(
[[ 1  2  3  4  5] 
 [ 6  7  8  9 10] 
 [11 12 13 14 15] 
 [16 17 18 19 20] 
 [21 22 23 24 25] 
 [26 27 28 29 30]])
```

and I want to extract these values from it just for the sake of learning :)

```
[[11,12],[16,17],[29,30]]
```

After so many tries I ended up in chatGPT which gave me a wrong answer :(.
chatGPT suggested this `a[[2, 3, 5], [0, 1, 1]]` but yeilded these values `[11 17 27]`.

Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: What is the logic behind it? What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried a[[2,3,5],0:2] but i know it will extract the 1st and 2nd values of rows 2,3,5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add commas to your array.

You can use numpy indexing:  **https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html**

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
       [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]])
```

---

```
print(a[2:4,0:2])
```

or

```
print(a[[2,3],0:2])
```

#output

```
array([[11, 12],
       [16, 17]])
```

---

```
print(a[5:,3:])
```

or

```
print(a[[5],3:])
```

#output

```
array([[29, 30]])
```

**Everything in one go:**

```
a[[2,3],0:2].tolist() + a[[5],3:].tolist()
```

or

```
a[2:4,0:2].tolist() + a[5:,3:].tolist()
```

#output

```
[[11, 12], [16, 17], [29, 30]]
```

Comment: Sorry for writing the code improperly but you missed my question here... Is it possible to get [[11,12],[16,17],[29,30]] in one array .

Comment: sure, one moment I will edit.

Comment: The `str` display of an array omits the commas.  The `repr` includes the commas and the `array()` header.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
a = np.arange(start=1, stop=31).reshape(6, 5)
print(np.array([a[2, 0:2], a[3, 0:2], a[5, 3:5]]))
```

Prints:

```
[[11 12]
 [16 17]
 [29 30]]
```